# Como ajustar el tamaño de la imagen de acuerdo al texto

Tags: html

Tengo un problema cuando ejecuto este código. Mi idea es que la imagen este acompañada de los textos pero a modo de currículum por así decirlo. El texto tendria que ir a la derecha de la imagen en sus respectivas columnas y la imagen ajustarse a ese tamaño. Creí que eso se solucionaba con el comando img-fluid pero no me estaría funcionando. Muchas gracias

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <img alt="perfil" class="img-fluid" src="../../../assets/perfil.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <p>Nombre</p>
            <p>Full Stack Developer Jr</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
            <span>
                <h1>Acerca de mí</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vel, magni cumque repellendus minima
                    temporibus nemo voluptatum a architecto enim itaque, aliquid labore possimus vitae nihil nisi
                    praesentium distinctio doloremque repudiandae?</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Solo me queda claro que el texto va a la derecha de la imagen, pero no sé que quieres hacer con el resto. Como lo tienes ahora son 3 columnas, imagen - texto - sobre mi. ¿Qué comportamiento quieres? ¿Puedes dar más información?

Comment: Quiero que quede de esta manera https://ibb.co/HXDcfTt